# Flink Insert records in sql table

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc, apache-flink

I am new to Apache Flink. I have a DataStream:

```
DataStream<Sample> countStream = ...

countStream.map(x -> {
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(...);
    PreparedStatement insertStatement = connection
                .prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Table1 (Col1, Col2) VALUES (?, ?);");
    // insert x in table
    return x;
});
```

I am not able to do a simple `insertStatement.executeUpdate();` because I receive a Object not serializable exception. How do I proceed?

Basically, I want to sink this streaming records into a sql table. If someone can guide me with a code snippet, it will be great.

`Sample` class is like:

```
class Sample {
    int col1;
    int col2;
}
```

Comment: I don't know flink, but a quick look at some of the API documentation leads me to conclude that you need to set the parameter values before calling execute. Something like insertStatement.setInt(1, x.col1); insertStatement.setInt(2, x.col2); perhaps? (I couldn't find specific references, so that syntax might not be correct.) Closest I found was https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/api/java/org/apache/flink/connector/jdbc/statement/FieldNamedPreparedStatement.html

Comment: @TN that didn't work, but thanks. This question might need Flink knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a JDBC sink for this. There's [an example in the documentation](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/connectors/datastream/jdbc/#full-example).

Rather than working with DataStreams, when using SQL tables it's often easier to use the Table API. [Here's a tutorial](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/try-flink/table_api/) you could start with that writes its results to a MySQL table.